# Can I "follow" games on Steam without getting desktop notifications?

Tags: steam

I recently started using Steam's "Follow" feature for a bunch of games so I would see their updates in my activity feed. Unfortunately this also came with the side effect of popup notifications in the desktop client whenever something new is posted.

The [Steam Discovery Update](http://store.steampowered.com/about/newstore) announcement about the feature doesn't mention desktop notifications. I've looked through the client settings but the only notifications I can disable are from friends. Is there some way to turn them off? I'd like to see these updates on my own time, but it's not worth getting desktop spam.

Answer (score 2):

As of this date, you cannot turn off the notifications from the groups you have subscribed. You cannot turn off the events notification as well.

In near future steam might implement this feature through updates because many people have reported this to steam including me. But for now we are out of luck.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure I am following a game but don't get desktop notifications. One thing I have done is disabled:

- "Notify me about additions or changes in my games, new releases, and upcoming releases."

This is found in the Steam settings->Interface as a checkbox. One main thing this does is stops the ads whenever steam restarts itself.

Comment: I already had that one disabled.

Comment: And I have it enabled but don't receive desktop notifications for Followed games, that I've noticed.

Comment: It only and only helps when you start steam for the first time. At that time if this is enabled then you see the update news of or the featured games on steam. Other than that, this setting doesn't do much about the question asked by OP.